# (Done) Req to reopen question: Is Severe itching (due to skin condition) reason enough to take off

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Is severe itching (due to skin condition) reason enough to take a day off?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115389/is-severe-itching-due-to-skin-condition-reason-enough-to-take-a-day-off)

This was closed as company specific.

This is a question about a disability, and how to handle it, this has NOTHING TO DO with law or specific companies.

Can we get this reopened please?

Comment: IMO your answer is good, but the question needs work. If the question asked specifically about how to handle it great, but the question being asked is whether X qualifies under the sick leave policy of employer Y in country Z. That's a textbook close in my view.

Comment: @Lilienthal IDrink took an edit and it seems to have addressed the problems you mentioned

Comment: @Lilienthal We're getting lazy if we're closing things when a quick edit can do.  Also, Name one sick leave policy anywhere that would not allow a chronic medical condition to be a reason to leave.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster Barring indentured servitude anyone can use any reason to leave work. But I can name dozens of countries where an employee's job or pay wouldn't be protected if he did. Regardless, the edit seems good. Note that we're supposed to close things when they need to be edited, it's why it's called "put on hold".

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks for clearing that up, I was too dumb to understand what hold means on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post was edited for improvements, and is now reopened.